# listView Problem in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem in listview.I my listview i have five columns(question_number,question_text,start_time,end_time,status). the first four columns will be fetch the data from the database.once the data has entered i have  to compare the starttime and with the current time.once the starttime is greater than current time then i have to update the status column as expired. otherwise i have to say not expired.

I have attached the code what i did so for.
I do no how to get the status updated in the status column.Please any one help me.thanks in advance.

```
     public void GetData()
       {
        try
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"User ID=sa;Password=password123;Initial Catalog=dish;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=ENMEDIA-CCDDFE5\ENMEDIA");
            //myConnection.Open();
            //SqlDataReader dr = new SqlCommand("SELECT question_text,question_id FROM otvtbl_question ", myConnection).ExecuteReader();

           // listView1.Columns.Clear();
            listView1.Items.Clear();

            myConnection.Open();
            String MyString1 = string.Format("SELECT question_id,question_text,start_time,end_time FROM otvtbl_question");

            SqlCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = MyString1;

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Adding The Column Name From The DataBase 
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                ColumnHeader ch = new ColumnHeader();
                ch.Text = dr.GetName(i);
                //listView1.Columns.Add(ch);
            }


            ListViewItem itmX;
            //Adding the Items To The Each Column
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                itmX = new ListViewItem();
                itmX.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();

                for (int i = 1; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    itmX.SubItems.Add(dr.GetValue(i).ToString());
                }
                listView1.Items.Add(itmX);
            }

            dr.Close();
            myConnection.Close();
          }
           catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error Message While Fetching
            MessageBox.Show("Error While Fetching the data From the DataBase" + ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            //Closing The Connection
            if (dr != null)
                dr.Close();

            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                myConnection.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Accept all your previous asked question's answers. so your accept is higher than it is right now.

Comment: i do know how to compare the start_time with current time and update the status column according.I am able to display  the other columns using the above code other than status column.can u help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ...
                listView1.Items.Add(itmX);

                if (dr.GetDateTime(2) > dr.GetDateTime(3))
                {
                    itmX.SubItems.Add("Expired");
                }
            }
```

Comment: sorry for late replay first.which u have posted is almost ok.But inside the if condition the item expired will have to be added to last column i.e status column.whether this will add the expired to  status column.

Comment: @bharathi - if you need to change a given column, just use `itmX.SubItems[n].Text = "Expired"`;