# Listview Problems. How to add the first element

Tags: c#, winforms

Questions I've already looked at:

[listView Problem in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879639/listview-problem-in-c-sharp)

[ListView problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431304/listview-problem)

---

Neither of these are my problem, and I can't find it using google either. When I try to add things to the listview, the entries start in the second column. As shown below:

[image: What's happening when I run it]

The code that is being used to add items:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.SubItems.Add(NameBox.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(Price.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(Cost.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(Stock.Text);
            InventoryList.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

I fail to see why this is happening. Is there any way around this? (I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, if it means anything)

---

It is a windows form application, that I am trying to develop for my business class. I already have a version of it working in Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you has actually looked just a tiny bit harder at the 1st link you would have found the answer yourself. (Or looked at MSDN)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I must have missed it.  I will check more thoroughly next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been years since I have used *WinForms*. However, (and from memory) the first column you seek is actually the `Text` property of the `ListViewItem`

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = "Luke, I am your father..."

// Subitems
item.SubItems.Add("Noooo!!!!!");
item.SubItems.Add(Price.Text);
//... etc
```

You can also use the constructor

[ListViewItem Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c277wk5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the ListViewItem class with the
> specified item text.

**Special Note** : When accessing the sub items

[ListViewItem.SubItems Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The first subitem in the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection is
> always the item that owns the subitems. When performing operations on
> subitems in the collection, be sure to reference index position 1
> instead of 0 to make changes to the first subitem.

Comment: That's an inspired answer. Not only that, it also worked.

Comment: Thanks, the 2 things you've highlighted have made understanding it a lot easier.